# Configure SMS autoreply suggestions

Tags: sms, automation

I periodically receive SMSs from automated systems that require a response. For one of them, all I need to do is reply "Yes" when it's convenient for me. Sometimes my phone (Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra - the tag [samsung-galaxy-s-21](/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-s-21) doesn't exist yet) suggests "Yes" and sometimes it suggests "Yes " which breaks the robot (`I'm sorry I didn't understand your text.`)

> Do you want to make a payment now?

> Yes

> I'm sorry I didn't understand your text. Do you want to make a payment now?

> Yes

> Payment made.

Another example is "Sure", which I use sometimes, but it's very flat. I'd prefer "Sure!" (with an exclamation mark) to pep it up, but I can't edit the message before it's sent.

> Can I call you to discuss the issue?

> Sure

vs

> Can I call you to discuss the issue?

> Sure!

Can I configure the suggestions that my phone offers?

Comment: While the question is about Samsung devices, is the app by any chance [Google Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging)? (because I noticed Google Messages and Gmail are some of the services that provide "[Smart Reply](https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9265111?hl=en#:~:text=Reply%20and%20share%20quickly%20with,suggested%20action%2C%20tap%20the%20action.)"). AFAIK, this is not customizable...

Comment: @AndrewT. The app is called just called Messages on my phone. I could only tell it was Google Messages by following the link you provided and seeing that the icon is the same.